# how to secure Url Variables into one unreadable viarable

Tags: php, encryption, qr-code

**Situation:**

I need to create QR-Codes, that contains login, password and 2 other informations A and B.

These QR-Codes are non public checkcards used for online authentification.

My Boss dont want to leave the password. show the qr codes and you are logged in

**Problem:**

I dont want easy to copy and semi easy to read qr codes to contain a plain text like 
www.example.com/login/?name=abc&password=def&A=ghi&B=jkl

I would much more prefer a solution 
www.example.com/login2/?var=dsldpjfeepfjwefpejwfp

**Question:**

Is there a good way to compress different variables into one unreadable variable and then at serverside to decompress it? I tried some encryption, but they will produce binarydata that is not url friendly (and its really LONG in most cases).

**Hint:**

I dont need complete encryption and safety. I just dont want to show plain passwords. 
I am Using PHP and cannot install new php modules, but scripts are ok.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`md5()`](http://php.net/md5), and on logging in check if:

```
m5d($password . $salt) == $_GET['password'];
```

Comment: No, im am suggesting sending an MD5-hashed over GET. Obviously having any login-information stored in an QR-code have its security-issues, but it looks like Umingo is aware of that.

Comment: Thanks, but i need to restore the values on the serverside and sending the md5 would exploit my $salt since if hashes are public transported you could reconstruct the salt that was used.

Comment: Then you have two options (that I can think of):
A) Encryption, gives indeed a long string, use http://php.net/base64_encode to convert binary data or;
B) If you need short urls: store a key with associated data in a database and use that key in your URL, as every URL-shortener (like tinyurl.com) does

Comment: 'would exploit my $salt' : if you use a per-user pepper besides your salt (as is always a good idea) you won't have this problem

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to encrypt it, you have two choices.

[Base64](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) - will create something like `dXNlcm5hbWV8cGFzc3dvcmR8dmFsdWV8c29tZXRoaW5n`

[UUencode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.convert-uuencode.php) - will create something like `A=7-E<FYA;65\<&%S<W=O<F1\=F%L=65\<V]M971H:6YG`

Both a trivially easy to reconstruct for the end user if she is determined.

If you want to make something like Base64 slightly more challenging to "decrypt" you could either run a basic substitution cipher on it first (a=b, b=c, etc) or apply a known shuffle to the string (swap character 1 with 2, swap 3 with 5, etc).

It's not perfect, but it will provide a small measure of defence against anyone who wants to reverse engineer what's in the code.